# SASS/SCSS loop through each div of the same name, and add content:after text

Tags: loops, sass, compass-sass

Is it possible in SCSS to loop through of series of say three divs like:

```
<div class="video_holder">
   <div class="video_title"></div>
</div>

<div class="video_holder">
   <div class="video_title"></div>
</div>

<div class="video_holder">
   <div class="video_title"></div>
</div>
```

And for each `video_title` add a property that does something like:

```
.video_title:after{ content: "number" }
```

So for each div, we'd start at 1.1 and go through to 1.x (whatever is needed)

I can't quite seem to get anything working based on other loops I've found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with css only, you don't need sass loop. You have to use css counter-increment.

First wrap all of your divs in another div:

```
<div class="video_counter_reset">
    <div class="video_holder">
       <div class="video_title"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="video_holder">
       <div class="video_title"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="video_holder">
       <div class="video_title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use this css:

```
.video_counter_reset {
    counter-reset: item;
}
.video_holder:after {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: "1." counter(item);
}
```

Read this [Smashing post](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/12/css-generated-content-counters/) for more details.

But there is a [sass mixin](http://gabri.me/2013/05/sass-mixin-for-auto-numbering-with-css/) you could use.